# System.UnauthorizedAccessException Sharepoint REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I am trying to access the sharepoint rest api in a html page via jquery ajax call. I am already logged into Sharepoint and authentication shouldnt be a problem. But when I try to access the a list by name it throws 403 (Forbidden) error. But the same url when I access it via the browser I get a response. Can any one help me on this issue?

[Here is the code I try to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDNI6.png)

Comment: are you querying from the same web or from a different web?

Comment: From another external Single Page Application

Comment: Is that SPA hosted by a SharePoint add in or is it totally separate?